# How can I prove this problem about ordering of differences of numbers?

Tags: algorithms

This is the problem: 
Given several real numbers (arbitrary amount and values) : $A_1,A_2 \ldots A_n$

Find the combination which yields the maximum value for the following formula:

$y = |A_x -A_y| + |A_y-A_z| \ldots$

Where all the numbers have to be used but no number can be used more than once.

and Where the number used as second part of an operant is the first number of the next.

For instance, if there are 3 numbers  X, Y and Z we may have this:

|X - Y| + |Y - Z|

My solution:
$|A_x -A_y|$ means the difference between these two numbers. We want thus maximize the differences between the number in a certain order.

To do so, I'd first sort the list from bigger to smaller.

Then I will pick number alternatively from the start and the end of the list. Thus ensuring the differences are biggest possible.
In other words I will start with the largest number, then I will choose the best possible decision at that moment which is the smaller. Then I am in the smaller, the best possible decision is the second-to-largest, etc.
You can think of the solution recursively also.

This is an eager process(as opposed to say Chess where you can not always choose the best play at a given moment on time). But I am sure yields the best result.

Now, this is the question:

**How can I prove this is true? How can make a mathematical proof of this?**

Or thinking more in general, is there any work on what kind of problems are suited for a eager algorithms? For instance, this process has a maximum, and it is of limited execution. This makes me think I can prove these kind of problems can be solved with 'best decision at each step' kind of algorthims. 
Anyone can through a light on this?

Comment: The word you want is "prove". "Probe" is something else...

Comment: I suppose you start with an even number of numbers. And another issue: in your example $A_y$ is used twice!

Comment: it was not clear, I've tried to show the explain better

Comment: This might work: show that if you don't use the difference between the biggest and smallest, you can get a bigger sum by using that difference. Then argue by induction.

Comment: Actually, your method doesn't give the maximum. Say the numbers are $0,3,4,7$. You would get $|7-0|+|0-4|+|4-3|$, but $|4-0|+|0-7|+|7-3|$ is bigger.

Comment: If the numbers are $X,Y,Z$, is $|X-Y|+|Y-Z|+|Z-X|$ a legitimate sum? You state that a number is not to be used more than once but your example $|X-Y|+|Y-Z|$ uses $Y$ twice.

Comment: Another example: if the numbers are $1,2,3,\dots,10$, I think you maximize by ordering them as $5,7,3,9,1,10,2,8,4,6$ giving $2+4+6+8+9+8+6+4+2=49$.

Comment: Thank you @GerryMyerson, I am convinced, this method will not give the maximum. 
It kind of invalidates the rest of the question. It will be cool to proof it does not work thought. Althought your examples should be enough proof. 
It seems like the real solution is almost the inverse of what I proposed. 
The extremes must be in the middle of the array and grow from there outwards.

Like :  1 , 10  -> 

9, 1, 10, 2  -> 

3, 9, 1, 10, 2, 8